# How to get storage size of a sharepoint site using API?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, microsoft-graph, site-usage

Is there a Graph or SharePoint API which returns storage size information of a site. I have checked:

[SP.Site.usage property (sp.js)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj244968(v%3Doffice.15))

But it is not a recommended version. Also I don’t want to use Powershell for this.

Answer (score 1):

**Using SharePoint REST API**:

The Microsoft is not documentation/updating the content related to `SP.Site.usage property` regularly. However it is still supported in SharePoint Online and you can use it without any issue.

Endpoint URL structure:

```
https://<siteurl>/_api/site/usage
```

It will will return the something like:

```
{
    "d": {
        "Usage": {
            "__metadata": {
                "type": "SP.UsageInfo"
            },
            "Bandwidth": "0",
            "DiscussionStorage": "0",
            "Hits": "0",
            "Storage": "221977142",
            "StoragePercentageUsed": 8.0754813825478775E-06,
            "Visits": "0"
        }
    }
}
```

`Storage` is a "Storage Used(in Bytes)" and not the "Total Storage". You can calculate the total amount of storage used based on `Storage` and `StoragePercentageUsed` in above result.

**Using Microsoft Graph**:

You can use `getSharePointSiteUsageDetail` to get details about SharePoint site usage.

1. [reportRoot: getSharePointSiteUsageDetail](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getsharepointsiteusagedetail?view=graph-rest-1.0)
2. [SharePoint site usage reports](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sharepoint-site-usage-reports?view=graph-rest-1.0)

**Using UI/Browser**:

You can also get this report from `Site Settings --> Site Collection Administration --> Storage Metrics`.

**Update from Comments**:

As of now, `getSharePointSiteUsageDetail` gets response only in CSV format. However you can convert it to JSON programatically.

Check below article for more details:

[Get All The SharePoint Site Collection Usage Details Using Graph API](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/get-all-the-sharepoint-site-collection-usage-details-using-graph-api/)

Comment: "getSharePointSiteUsageDetail" returns a csv. Is there a way to get json in response?

Comment: Also "Visits" field is not updated and always remains 0 even after multiple visits to the site

Comment: Check updated answer to convert csv to JSON.

Comment: Actually I have seen the that Microsoft API's gets throttled very easily if we use csv as output. I had a bad experience in the past because of this. This is the reason for not taking output in csv

Comment: Have you tried it? Is it working for you?

Comment: I have tried it. It works fine for now but AFAIK it is not scalable

Comment: I understand. But this is the only way available currently. You cannot get the response in JSON using `getSharePointSiteUsageDetail` directly. It will return the response in CSV only.

Comment: Hi @MridulSharma, Did you solved this issue?