# Power Automate to read Site collection Storage warning level

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, storage-quota

Is there a way to get the configured warning level of a site collection in Power Automate? I see how we can connect to get current storage used and current percentage used, which you can then calculate the storage allocation amount. But - that doesn't tell me the value of the warning level.

I want to run a script daily to check if a site has exceeded its warning threshold, and not have to wait until the end of the week when SharePoint sends those notices. (I can't have my site block users from uploading files from Monday through Friday while waiting on a notice to be sent on Saturday.)

I have seen this is DIRT SIMPLE to do in PowerShell. But cannot find anywhere how to get the data in Power Automate.

Comment: There are some API available to get that details which you can call from your Power Automate. See similar thread [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/281577/how-to-get-storage-size-of-a-sharepoint-site-using-api)

Comment: @KalpeshVaghela - I have seen this article. This operation does not give you the configured Threshold percentage. This is the key piece of data I need. I can calculate the percentage USED by the two amounts in this link - but that doesn't tell me if the threshold has been reached. Not every site has the same threshold - so I can't use a "fixed" number.